# Overflow into the Text widget ignores the available space

Tags: flutter

Without specifying the maximum number of lines, the text is truncated after 1 line. With a larger value than the size of the parent allows, the text goes beyond the parent and there are no errors.

[image]
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyaD3.png)

```
   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: SafeArea(
            child: Material(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(
                      'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                          ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                          'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                          ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                          'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                          ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                          'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                          ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                          'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                          ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      maxLines: 122,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

softWrap does not affect in any way, and also does not help to wrap Flexible and Expanded.

[image]

Comment: hi, it would help if you specify what is your question or desired outcome

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Desired result:
"dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y
 guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij ..." 
or at least an overflow error

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your SingleChildScrollView in a Text widget and you will get what you are looking for.

```
      return MaterialApp(
  home: SafeArea(
    child: Material(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.black12,
            height: 100,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
            child: Text(
              'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
              ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
              'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
              ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
              'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
              ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
              'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
              ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
              'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
              ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 122,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I want the text to be cropped by as much as it fits in the parent widget.

Comment: @Mikhail you can change param overflow to   TextOverflow.fade,

Comment: Is there a solution where I can use TextOverFlow.ellipsis correctly?

Comment: @Mikhail see changes in the code

Answer (score 0):

just remove `height: 100,` and it will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The essence of height is precisely in demonstrating the behavior of the Text widget

Answer (score 0):

Remove following two lines from your code.

```dart
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    maxLines: 122,
```

**Edited**

And add `textAlign` as `justify`

```
textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
This has no effect

Comment: I made a change, this may help.

Comment: Thanks, but it also has no effect

Answer (score 0):

replace TextOverflow.ellipsis with : `overflow: TextOverflow.visible,` or `overflow: TextOverflow.clip,`

> TextOverflow.visible: text will be visible but you will have to
> increase height of container in your case
>
> TextOverflow.clip: text will be visible which container height can
> contain

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that "Text Overflow.ellipsis" is not working correctly.  It cuts the text either after 1 line or after the specified maximum number of lines, regardless of the size of the parent.

Comment: Please go through answer again maybe you misunderstood it
Just try TextOverflow.clip or TextOverFlow.visible

Comment: Everything is fine with TextOverflow.clip or TextOverFlow.visible. The problem is observed only when using TextOverFlow.ellipsis

Comment: Try using flexible widget as parent of Container

Comment: This has no effect

Comment: Can you add screen which you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

`maxLines` does give this weird behaviour.
Since you have hardcoded height, just go with hardcoding maxLines that would fit that height. then as suggested by some answers, wrap your text with `Expanded`. as you wanted, this will show overflow warning if `maxLines` don't fit in given height.

```
Container(height: 100, child: Column(
      children: [
           Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                      ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                      'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                      ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                      'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                      ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                      'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                      ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                      'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                      ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                      'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                      ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                      'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                      ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij'
                      'dsf sdf ds fs dfsdfdf  iuh gyj gy y'
                      ' guygiukjh  uiygihjo; rdtfyguhijok rftyguhij yguhij',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 14,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

      ],
    ));
```